# Outer Join or NOT IN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Need a little help solving problem. Apologies if this is vague which is why I need help. Show The title ID, title, publisher id, publisher name, and terms for all books that have never been sold.  This means that there are no records in the Sales Table.  Use OUTER JOIN or NOT IN against SALES table.  In this case, the terms are referring to the items on the titles table involving money. ( Price, advance, royalty ).

I've come up with the following code and there are no records returned. I've looked at the tables and no records should be returned. Not sure my code is correct based on using the OuterJoin or NOT IN. Thanks!

```
SELECT titles.title_id, 
       titles.title, 
       publishers.pub_id, 
       sales.payterms,   
       titles.price, 
       titles.advance, 
       titles.royalty
  FROM publishers 
       INNER JOIN titles 
                  ON publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id 
       INNER JOIN sales 
                  ON titles.title_id   = sales.title_id
 WHERE (sales.qty = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you need it to change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` for your sales table. Then check for `NULL` on any of the columns from the sales table.

```
SELECT     titles.title_id, titles.title, publishers.pub_id, sales.payterms,   
           titles.price, titles.advance, titles.royalty

FROM       publishers INNER JOIN
           titles ON publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id LEFT JOIN
           sales ON titles.title_id = sales.title_id
WHERE     sales.qty IS NULL
```

Comment: No need for parentheses there.

Comment: @ypercube Very true, I just changed as little of the original query as possible.

Comment: Okay, I see the relationship. As a beginner could the Where also be written as sales.qty = 0? Obviously I have a lot to learn as a beginner. Is there a reason for using IS NULL? This is covered later...thanks.

Comment: @allendks45 You can't use sales.qty = 0 as that row in the sales table doesn't exist, that what using a LEFT JOIN does, so you need to check if one of the columns is null. Using sales.qty = 0 will effectively nullify the effect of the LEFT JOIN and also only return records where the sales.qty is 0, of which I assume there are none as you mentioned getting no rows back in you original question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are using `INNER JOIN` so it will only return records that match the join condition which is not what you want. You should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) and check that the `sales` side is null (meaning there's no record matching).

```
SELECT     titles.title_id, titles.title, publishers.pub_id, sales.payterms,   
           titles.price, titles.advance, titles.royalty

FROM       publishers INNER JOIN
           titles ON publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
           sales ON titles.title_id = sales.title_id
WHERE     sales.title_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

IS NULL Means that a data value does not exist in the database. And just change your INNER JOIN TO LEFT JOIN.
use this..

```
SELECT titles.title_id, 
   titles.title, 
   publishers.pub_id, 
   sales.payterms,   
   titles.price, 
   titles.advance, 
   titles.royalty
FROM publishers 
   INNER JOIN titles 
              ON publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id 
   LEFT JOIN sales 
              ON titles.title_id   = sales.title_id
WHERE     (sales.qty IS NULL)
```